# How to Build fieldSets with fixed width/height & 2 columns of checkboxes

Tags: html, css, jsp

its me again!  I am dynamically building fieldsets because the # of them could change according to the database.  To accomodate for rel estate on the page.  I want to change my current set-up of fieldSets to have a fixed width/height and have 2 coumns of checkboxes instead of one to see how it will layout on the page.  Thanks:

BTW  Im not good at styling thats why I asked the question :)

jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${FieldMap}" var="detFieldEntry">     
    <fieldset class="det">         
    <legend>${FieldEntry.key}</legend>  
    <c:forEach items="${FieldEntry.value}" var="detBean">    
         <input type="checkbox" name="fieldNames" value="${Bean.fieldName}" 
         <c:if test="${form.fieldNameMap[Bean.fieldName]}">checked="checked"   </c:if>>${Bean.displayName}</input>          
         </br>    
   </c:forEach> 
   </fieldset> 
</c:forEach>
```

css:

```
table.det
{
}

table.det td
{ border: none; }

fieldset.det 
{     
display:block;
float:left;

font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:20px;
border:2px solid #CCCCCC;

}
 fieldset.det legend
{
    padding:2px 5px;
    border:2px solid #CCCCCC;
    font-weight:  bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? Check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hw9ZN/) and let me know.

Maybe like this?

```
print <fieldset>
print <legend>
columns = 2
offset = 0
class = "left"
count = dbResult.length() // Say 9
rows = count / columns // you want to round up to use the next whole int, so 4.5 should be 5. 
for i=0, i < columns, i++ {
    print <div class="<%=class%>"
    for k=0, k < rows, k++ {
        print <span><input>k+offset<label></span>
    }
    offset = rows
    print </div>
    class = "right"
}
print </fieldset>
```

Comment: Yes sir...thats exactly what i was looking for

Comment: How would I implement this in my loop though?

Comment: You'll set a fixed number of rows for each side and use that as your iterator (i). So I would do a count when you get your number of form fields, say it's 9. You then do a quick division problem so each side will contain 5 fields (5 on the left and 4 on the right). Iterate through the left DIV then close it and start the right DIV and iterator through the remainder.

Comment: Maybe some pseudo-code will help?
`print <fieldset>
print <legend>
columns = 2
offset = 0
class = "left"
count = dbResult.length() // Say 9
rows = count / columns // you want to round up to use the next whole int, so 4.5 should be 5. 
for i=0, i < columns, i++ {
 print <div class="<%=class%>"
 for k=0, k < rows, k++ {
  print <span><input>k+offset<label></span>
 }
 offset = rows
 print </div>
 class = "right"
}
print </fieldset>`